# ParseFilePipeBuilder throws error for wrong filetype, but file gets uploaded as well despite the error , NestJs v10^

Tags: validation, nestjs, pipe, mime-types

I'm using `new ParseFilePipeBuilder()` to validate the uploaded file type. It does throw error for wrong file type. But it also uploads that wrong file type file as well. That I don't want , I want to only upload the **specific file type(i.e png)** , and If user try to upload a file whose mime type or extention type is not `png`, will face an error and won't be able to upload the file.

**Code**

```
import {
  Controller, Post, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors,Request, HttpStatus,
  ParseFilePipeBuilder,
} from '@nestjs/common';
    
    @Post('/upload)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './path',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const uniqueIdentifier: string = new Date().getTime().toString();
          return cb(
            null,
            `${uniqueIdentifier}${file.originalname.replace(/\s/g, '')}`,
          );
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiBody({
    schema: {
      title: 'xyz',
      type: 'object',
      properties: { file: { type: 'string', format: 'binary' } },
    },
    description: 'Upload File',
  })
  uploadCv(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
        .addFileTypeValidator({ fileType: 'png' })
        .build({ errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY }),
    )
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Request() req,
  ){../}
```

Answer (score 0):

The files get uploaded and saved to disk (or other storage device) by multer during the `FileInterceptor`, as interceptors run before pipes. Then the pipe eventually throws the error, which multer is now unaware about, so there's no way for multer to clean up the file. You could implement some cleanup logic in an exception filter though, as `req.file` will be present, and you should be able to take the existing path and then remove it

Comment: Then I don't understand the benefit of built in validation provided by NestJs if they only just do nothing in the name of validation, and we have to implement the logic for validation by our own.

Answer (score 0):

We can make a simple solution if NestJs built in validation pipes don't work. We can put a check inside `@UseInterceptor` and  `throw Exception` if the `file extension` does not match to our specific extension type. And the **file won't be uploaded** , if exception is thrown, and only the specified extension type files will be uploaded.

```
@UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './path',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const allowedFileExtensions = ['.png'];
          const uniqueIdentifier: string = new Date().getTime().toString();
          let uploadingFileExtention = extname(file.originalname);
          if (!allowedFileExtensions.includes(uploadingFileExtention)) {
            return cb(
              new UnprocessableEntityException('Unsupported file'),
              null,
            );
          }
          return cb(
            null,
            `${uniqueIdentifier}${file.originalname.replace(/\s/g, '')}`,
          );
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
```